# Accessing image file contents after UIImagePicker selection

Tags: ios4, uiimage, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePicker selection, and on the selection of an image it returns an info dictionary with the following entries:

```
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image"
UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage:0x3333333>"
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000001&ext=JPG"
```

How can I access the BLOB contents of the selected image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do this?

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
```

**Alternatively**

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; // or you can use UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage too
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

and then access the [`bytes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/bytes).

Comment: Whenever I use the reference URL, the NSData is coming back as (null).

Comment: Actually it should've been `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];`, you can also get the `NSData` object from the image. I've added this to answer.